# Returning 5-digit date in Debug.Print without formatting the cell

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**

I am looking to get the 5-digit date from a cell which is formatted to display a date. 
 The 5-digit date should only be the immediate window (via `debug.print`).

My testing with results in the *Script* section (bottom).

I have a feeling that the answer will involve `datediff()+2` based on the testing I did, but I can't figure out why that +2 is needed and don't want to just add that in if it's wrong in the future.

---

**Issue:**

I don't seem to be able to display the correct 5-digit date (as displayed with "general" format) by means of `Debug.Print`.

---

**Question:**

How do you get the 5-digit date, most often displayed with General-formatting, to display in the immediate window (`debug.print`) without first converting the cell's `.numberformat`?

---

**Script:**

```
Dim rng As Range, d1 As String, d2 As String
Set rng = Cells(1, 1) 'value = 20190101

Debug.Print Format(rng.Value, "@") 'returns 20190101
Debug.Print rng.NumberFormat = "General" 'returns "false"
Debug.Print Format(rng.value, "General") 'returns "Ge0oral" due to the "n" being recognized for a format

d1 = "1900/01/01"
d2 = rng.Value
Debug.Print 40729 + DateDiff("d", d1, d2) 'returns 84195
Debug.Print DateDiff("d", d1, d2) 'returns 43466

rng.NumberFormat = "General"
Debug.Print rng.Value 'returns 43468, but required formatting the cell
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two methods that come to mind when you are wanting to print the numerical representation of the date without changing the formatting of the cell.

The best way to do it is using the `.Value2` property.

```
Debug.Print Rng.Value2
```

The 'less recommended' approach is by using the `CDbl()` function. I would use this moreso for variables and `.Value2` for ranges.

```
Debug.Print CDbl(Rng.Value)
```

Or for variables

```
Dim d as Date
d = #01/01/2019#

Debug.Print CDbl(d)
Debug.Print CLng(d) 'If not using time - date only
```

Comment: @BigBen gave you both upvotes but took K's due to the additional effort.  Apprently the `datediff()` works and i dont' need the +2, but for some reason when I convert the numberformat before debug.print it keeps adding that +2... the `.value2` seems much more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

[`Range.Value2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2) doesn't use the `Date` type, so you can just `Debug.Print rng.Value2`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice layout Cyril =)

To complement the other answers: Whereas `Value2` is the more appropriate way to go, another very simple possibility is:

```
Debug.Print rng*1
```

Comment: I'm a bit preferable to the layout ~_*  Thanks for the additional input; nice to have alternatives.